# A porta se abriu é intransitivo?

Tags: transitividade-verbal, verbos-intransitivos

Vamos dizer que a porta é o próprio sujeito e ela se abriu sozinha. O verbo abrir se torna intransitivo?

Comment: Não seria um verbo pronominal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sim**, isso mesmo, torna-se intransitivo. Trata-se de um verbo de alternância causativo-incoativa, com uma variante transitiva e uma variante intransitiva. Mais precisamente, a variante intransitiva do verbo é inacusativa, o que significa que o sujeito é, não o agente como nos verbos inergativos ou intransitivos puros (e portanto não podemos dizer que a porta se abra a si mesma), mas antes o experienciador.

Como outros exemplos de verbos de alternância causativa, temos *quebrar*, *terminar*, *partir* e *ferir*. Como exemplos de verbos inacusativos que não alternam temos *chegar*, *crescer*, *florescer* ou *aparecer*. Para verbos inergativos, podemos dar como exemplo *correr* ou *gritar*.

Comment: Artefacto, quando busco pelos termos chave que você menciona, acho quase só teses e dissertações, que me pareceram um pouco impenetráveis numa leitura rápida, então não posso dizer ter entendido tua resposta. Você poderia explicar o significado deles em um pouco mais de detalhe? E, uma pergunta: baseei minha resposta em meros dicionários, ela é apenas superficial ou chega a estar errada? (Nesse último caso, eu a apagaria.)

Comment: @stafusa as teses de mestrado tendem a ter uma introdução onde com as definições que queres. A tua pergunta está, sim, errada. O clítico _se_ tem muitas funções diferentes (apassivador, nominativo, reflexo, anti-causativo, inerente). Para _se_ ser reflexo, a porta tinha de ser simultaneamente o agente e o experienciador. Mas uma porta, a não ser em contos fantásticos, não é animada e dificilmente pode ser responsável por se abrir a si mesma. Aliás, um dos testes para veres que não há construção reflexiva é não poderes dizer _a porta abriu-se a si mesma_.

Comment: Artefacto, obrigado pelo retorno. Adicionei então uma observação à minha resposta, direcionando à tua. Quanto as teses, é como já expliquei: "um pouco impenetráveis numa leitura rápida", com o que quero dizer justamente que essas definições eram impróprias para mim, i.e., feitas em termos que eu também desconhecia. Nada que não se possa aprender, claro (inclusive agora já tenho um entendimento um pouco melhor que antes), mas que não cabe na leitura rápida que pude fazer.

Comment: Uma porta não pode abrir a si mesma? Em que século vocês vivem, 19? Nunca viram, entraram, imaginaram, assistiram uma porta de loja de shopping? 
hahaha, me desculpem, mas ando dando umas risadas da interpretação da gramática meio... como eu diria... Dom Pedro I...

Comment: @RodrigoFontana Não, uma porta não se pode abrir a si mesma... Uma porta pode-se abrir sozinha, ou **por** si mesma, quando muito (causa interna, mas não agentiva).

Comment: Me é estranha essa maneira de ler a porta abrir 'por si mesma' particularizando o 'a si mesma'. É de novo, me parece, uma maneira antes de 1950 de gramática. Quando uma porta abrir sozinha significava: 'Bernoulli esteve ali... passou um vento ali, a diferença de pressão dinâmica abriu a porta, sem que ninguém a tocasse'. Em 1990, quando as portas abrem a si mesmas ao verem um sujeito, por advento de suas bugigangas eletrônicas, não percebo a diferença.
No mínimo eu diria que é bem particular (de novo). Talvez você possa endossar essas colocações com algumas referências.

Answer (score 2):

Não, com esse significado o verbo *abrir* é sempre transitivo [1]. A forma que ele assume no exemplo "*a porta se abriu*" é, por conta do pronome oblíquo *se*, [pronominal](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbos-pronominais/) - e o objeto é a própria porta.

<sub>[1] Cf. esta [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5066/2764), que afirma que o verbo nesse caso não é nem transitivo, nem intransitivo puro, mas *inacusativo* e, mais que *objeto* do verbo, a porta seria o *experimentador*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me que aqui temos um caso de *voz passiva sintética* formada pelo *partícula apassivadora SE* e pelo verbo principal. Neste caso, parece-me que PORTA é o *sujeito paciente* da verbo na voz passiva, pois se perguntássemos "o que se abriu?", a resposta que obteríamos seria o termo "a porta". Na voz passiva sintética, não temos o agente da ação como temos na analítica. Creio que meu ponto de vista pode estar equivocado, mas é desta forma que percebi a sua construção acima e a analisei.

[image: Diagrama da sua construção sintática. Eu fiz da forma mais simplificada possível.]

Comment: A pergunta não dá muito contexto, mas para estarmos ante uma passiva sintética seria mais muito provável que se dissesse «abriu-se a porta», ex.: «às 9h00, abriu-se a porta para os clientes entrarem».

Comment: Certo. Muito obrigado por corrigir meu ponto de vista. Sou novo na área de Letras e gramática hehe.